# Final in android Java

Tags: java, android, final

Hi am new to android development and have been watching The New Bostons Videos and have a question about the final modifier. Why when I type something like this

```
TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);
display.setText("LEFT!!!");
```

in to my OnCreate class do I need to add the final modifier to display.

Comment: You should seriously start with a simple Java tutorial and work your way up.

Comment: Do you actually have to make `display` final here, or only if you move it into a `Runnable`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4 final variables.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If this is what I think it is (using the variable in a "closure"), it can be a bit tricky even for someone with some Java experience.

Comment: @chrylis You're right, but they'll probably learn what to look for and unravel the thread.

Comment: The reason I am asking is because Eclipse is sending an error message out when I don't and really I am just wondering why it is sending the error out.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I have watch all the The New Bostons Videos Basic Java tutorials where else do you suggest I go to learn  more java  any good video tutorials you know of on the internet.

Comment: Personally, I haven't watched any video tutorials. I usually go straight to the documentation on such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't ***have*** to use the `final` modifier but it is good coding practice, for any Java variable, to use the `final` modifier if you don't intend to ever assign another object to the variable.  This means that, if you see it assigned at the top of the method, as another developer you can skim through loads of code without worrying that the variable might have been reassigned somewhere else in the method.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't `final` variable's value cannot be changed during `runtime` its only can be initialized so if you

```
final TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);
display.setText("LEFT!!!");
```

then write

```
display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
```

this will give you compilation error